# Numerical Change of Variables

Tags: numerical-methods, change-of-variable, numerical-calculus

If I have $f(x)$ represented by 2 arrays. One array is the arrays of $x$ while the other is output from $f(x)$. So basically a numerical representation of the function. If I don't know what $f(x)$ is, can I still change the variable. For example can I calculate $f(\frac{1}{x})$ from what I know.

Comment: Well, you know the values of $f(1/x)$ at the sampled points $1/x_i$, so you can use a quadrature formula to have an estimate of the integral. No need to "change the variable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you know $f(x_i)=f_i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$. Consider the function $g(x)=f(1/x)$ and the points $y_i=1/x_i$. Then you know $g(y_i)=f_i$. Now you can use any quadrature rule (for instance the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Non-uniform_grid)) to get an estimate of the integral of $g$.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. It makes sense. I think I was working on this problem for too long and got lost in some details. Thanks again